# Removing a cell in a row in Apex

Tags: apex, dml

Im jut wondering what is the best way to remove a single cell/column (I dont know what the word in Apex is) from a row. So I have a bunch of reports and I want to remove the deal from them. I was thinking the below but I was wondering if there is a better way:

```
List<Report__c > reports = [Select Id From Report__c Where Id = :dealId];

for(Report__c report : reports)
{
    report.Deal__c = '';
}

upsert reports ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to blank this field then set it to null. Note your query will return single record but if you want to do in bulk then use data loader, data loader.io or 
Write batch for this .

Or if you want to permanent delete this field then go to setup object select this report object search this field and click on delete .

Salesforce give you 15 day limit to undelete the field and restore the data but after that you will permanent loose your data .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There wont be that many, max 100. But I dont know what you mean my query will only return a single record? the Select will get all reports that have the specified deal id. Also, I cant go into salesforce to do it through clicks, this is being done in code.

Comment: When you are specifying Id (Salesforce Primary Key) in a query, which means that you are trying to retrive a record with that perticular ID. It returns only one record. In your above query I dont think it will return any records, as you are querying Report__c object by dealId in where condition. Id's are always unique and will never be same across objects.

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. The Table actually has a column called Deal__c so that is correct.

Comment: @discodowney In Salesforce we called them field.